# Texture not mapping correctly over square root sheet

Tags: plotting, textures

I'm trying to texture a set of concentric annuli over `ParametricPlot3D` surfaces of various functions but the mapping is not centered and not covering the entire surface I wish to texture.  Here is a simple example of texturing a few annuli over $\sqrt{z}$ which shows the problem:

```
    p1 = Graphics@{Red, Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/4, 3/4}, {-Pi/2, Pi/6}]};
p2 = Graphics@{Blue, Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/4, 3/4}, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/4}]};
p3 = Graphics@{Green, Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/4, 3/4}, {3 Pi/4, 2 Pi}]};
plotB = Show[{p1, p2, p3}];
ParametricPlot3D[{Re@z, Im@z, Re@Sqrt[z]} /. z -> r Exp[I t], {r, 0, 
  3/4}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Texture[plotB]}, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

and I don't understand `TextureCoordinateFunction` enough to solve the problem if this is the cause.  Note also if I just download an example:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Re@z, Im@z, Re@Sqrt[z]} /. z -> r Exp[I t], {r, 0, 
  3/4}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "Roof"}]]}, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

The texture successfully covers the entire plot:

[image]

Can someone help me with this problem please?  Couldn't find any similar example in the forum or in the help files nor various attempts at manipulating the Texture coorinates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We set the `PlotRange` and the  `Background` to `Black` in order to full fill the graphics region.

```
texture = 
 Graphics[{{Red, Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/4, 3/4}, {-Pi/2, Pi/6}]}, {Blue, 
    Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/4, 3/4}, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/4}]}, {{Green, 
     Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/4, 3/4}, {3 Pi/4, 2 Pi}]}}}, PlotRange -> .75,
   PlotRangeClipping -> True, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Re@z, Im@z, Re@Sqrt[z]} /. z -> r Exp[I t], {r, 0, 
  3/4}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Texture[texture]}, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That did it.  I found didn't need the `BackGround->Black` however, I was passing a `Show` object to `Texture` rather than a pure `Graphics` object as you do above and not using the `PlotRangeClipping->True` as well.  Surprised  the texture does not bleed-across branch-cuts but has sharp discontinuities which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The principal problem is `PlotRange`, as cvgmt shows, but I'd solve the problem with `MeshShading`.

`PlotRange`:

```
p1 = Graphics@{Red, Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/4, 3/4}, {-Pi/2, Pi/6}]};
p2 = Graphics@{Blue, Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/4, 3/4}, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/4}]};
p3 = Graphics@{Green, Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/4, 3/4}, {3 Pi/4, 2 Pi}]};
plotB = Show[{p1, p2, p3}, PlotRange -> 3/4];
ParametricPlot3D[{Re@z, Im@z, Re@Sqrt[z]} /. z -> r Exp[I t], {r, 0, 
  3/4}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Texture[plotB]}, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

`MeshShading`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Re@z, Im@z, Re@Sqrt[z]} /. z -> r Exp[I t], {r, 0, 
  3/4}, {t, -Pi, Pi},
 Mesh -> {{1/4, 3/4}, 
   NumericalSort@Mod[{Pi/6, 3 Pi/4, 2 Pi}, 2 Pi, -Pi]},
 MeshShading -> 
  Transpose@{{White, White, White}, {Green, Red, Blue}},
 MeshStyle -> None,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]